# Python AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to python and pandas and I'm working a project for a distance matrix.
I got an API that gets distance data from two points and I 'd like to export to excel or csv.

I'm getting a module "pandas" has no attribute "Dataframe"

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd



origin="Centro Hospitalar Universitário de São João, E. P. E"
destination="Braga"
api="api"

response=requests.get("https://api.distancematrix.ai/maps/api/distancematrix/json?        origins="+origin+"&destinations="+destination+"&key="+api+"")

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())


df=pd.Dataframe.from_dict(response.json())
df.to_excel("filepath")
```

I tried capitalizing Dataframe and made sure that I don't have any pd variable or pandas.py file name

Answer (score 1):

It is [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), python is [case-sensitive](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-case-sensitive/), so use it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json())
```